# Server Send()s not working with Select() properly

Tags: c, select, client, server, winsock

I'm using select() on my server so that it can handle multiple clients at once, it can receive information from all the clients at once using select() with recv() calls, but when i want to send information to multiple clients using select() with send() it will not send to multiple clients at once. It will send to one client, the rest of the clients get blocked, once the working client exits the next client gets handled. Is my select() logic wrong?

```
fd_set master;    // master file descriptor list
fd_set read_fds;  // temp file descriptor list for select()
fd_set write_fds;  // temp file descriptor list for select()
int fdmax;        // maximum file descriptor number

int newfd;        // newly accept()ed socket descriptor
struct sockaddr_storage remoteaddr; // client address
socklen_t addrlen;

FD_ZERO(&master);    // clear the master and temp sets
FD_ZERO(&read_fds);
FD_ZERO(&write_fds);

result = NULL;
recvbuflen = DEFAULT_BUFLEN;

memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(hints));
hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;
hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;

// Resolve the server address and port
funcRtrnVal = getaddrinfo(NULL, DEFAULT_PORT, &hints, &result);
if (funcRtrnVal != 0) {
    printf("getaddrinfo failed with error: %d\n", funcRtrnVal);
        WSACleanup();
}

// Create a SOCKET for connecting to server
ListenSocket = socket(result->ai_family, result->ai_socktype, result->ai_protocol);

// add the listener to the master set
FD_SET(ListenSocket, &master);

// keep track of the biggest file descriptor
fdmax = ListenSocket; // so far, it's this one

    if (ListenSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        printf("socket failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
        freeaddrinfo(result);
        WSACleanup();
    }

// Setup the TCP listening socket
funcRtrnVal = bind(ListenSocket, result->ai_addr, (int)result->ai_addrlen);

// error check 'bind'
    if (funcRtrnVal == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("bind failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        freeaddrinfo(result);
        closesocket(ListenSocket);
        WSACleanup();
    }

freeaddrinfo(result);

// listen for incoming connections
funcRtrnVal = listen(ListenSocket, SOMAXCONN);

// error check 'listen'
    if (funcRtrnVal == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("listen failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ListenSocket);
        WSACleanup();
    }

while (true)
{
    read_fds = master; // copy it
    write_fds = master;

    // run select statement
    if (select(fdmax + 1, &read_fds, &write_fds, NULL, NULL) == -1)
    {
        //perror("select");
        //exit(4);
    }

    // run through the existing connections looking for data to read/write
    for (int i = 0; i <= fdmax; i++)
    {
        if (FD_ISSET(i, &read_fds))
        {
            printf("read triggered\n");

            if (i == ListenSocket)
            {
                // Accept a client socket
                newfd = accept(ListenSocket, NULL, NULL);

                // error check 'accept'
                    if (newfd == INVALID_SOCKET) {
                        printf("accept failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
                        closesocket(ListenSocket);
                        WSACleanup();
                    }

                if (newfd == -1) {
                    //perror("accept");
                }
                else
                {
                    FD_SET(newfd, &master); // add to master set

                    if (newfd > fdmax) {    // keep track of the max
                        fdmax = newfd;
                    }
                }
            }

            else
            {
                // Receive from client
                funcRtrnVal = recv(i, recvbuf, recvbuflen, 0);

                // if we received a byte stream
                if (funcRtrnVal > 0)
                {
                    // get the length of the byte stream
                    int messageLength = (int)strlen(recvbuf);

                    printf("%s\n", recvbuf);

                }

                // empty out all the buffs
                memset(recvbuf, 0, sizeof(recvbuf));

                //close(i); // bye!
                //FD_CLR(i, &master); // remove from master set
            }
        }

        if (FD_ISSET(i, &write_fds))
        {
            printf("write triggered\n");

            // Send the data to the client
            funcRtrnVal = send(i, sendbuf, (int)strlen(sendbuf), 0);

            if (funcRtrnVal > 0)
            {
                printf("Server sent sendbuf: %s\n", sendbuf);

                // empty out the sendbuf
                memset(sendbuf, 0, sizeof(sendbuf));
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: 'Will not send' isn't a problem description. What happens instead?

Comment: Sorry, edited the question.

Comment: A comment. You're misusing `writefds`. When you have something to write to a peer, just write it, and only if `write()` causes `EAGAIN/EWOULDBLOCK` do you then need to enter that socket into `writefds` so you can select on its writability. That also implies that you need to save the buffer being sent somehow. When that socket becomes writeable, send, and as long as that doesn't fail again in the same way you can then remove that socket from `writefds`. NB `printf("Server sent sendbuf: %s\n", sendbuf)` should be `printf("Server sent sendbuf: %.*s\n", funcRtrnVal, sendbuf)`.

Comment: So what is the problem with calling select on all the connected sockets' writability? Wouldnt it just check to see if the socket is calling a recv(), then select will return saying the socket is ready to be written to? Am i misunderstanding how select is used for writes (sends)?

Comment: You're writing C, not C++.

Comment: The rest of the program im writing is c++, its just the code im showing you is all c, the rest of the program is c++, so without thinking i put the tag as c++, ill fix now :)

Comment: The problem is that sockets are nearly always writable, except when their send buffer is full, so the selector will never block, so you will constantly write, so ... The `writefds` are therefore only useful to detect when an *unwriteable* socket has *just become* writeable. I don't understand your question about 'check if the socket is calling a `recv()`'.